# How to simulate option selection? click() doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I want to simulate a user click on certain option, so I use `click()` on the `<option>` but it doesn't work:

```js
let select = document.getElementById("select");
select.addEventListener("change", changeSelection);

function changeSelection() {
  console.log("Clicked");
}

let option = select.querySelector(`option[value="3"]`);
option.click();
```

```html
<select id="select">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: `option.selected = true` should do it

Comment: `select.value = '3';` and trigger change

Comment: I tried your code, it worked for me.

Comment: The problem with these methods is that it doesn't trigger the listeners I have as if I actually chose using the select dropdown

Comment: @Emilien my code you mean? Because in the snippet it doesn't work

Comment: @Stackerito Even in the snippet it works for me. Every time I select an option it shows "Clicked" in the console. Isn't it what you want ?

Comment: @Emilien What browser are you using? It is not happening for me on Chrome OSX. Option support is non consistent in browsers.

Comment: @Emilien The problem is different - it's that it doesn't show "Clicked" immediately when you run the snippet and changes the selected option to `3` - because if you see at the bottom I try to trigger `click()` on the `option` with value `3`. It still works if you manually change it yourself but that's ok. But not when I tried to trigger it using `click()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with option in a select is they are a "windowed" element and you really have issue working with them.

Typically if you want to select an option either you set the value of the select or if it is multiple select, set the selected attributes of the options. Since setting the value does not trigger change events, you would need to manually trigger it.

**Single Select**

```js
let select = document.getElementById("select");
select.addEventListener("change", changeSelection);

function changeSelection() {
  console.log("Clicked", this.value);
}

select.value = 3;
select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

```html
<select id="select">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

**Multiple select**

```js
let select = document.getElementById("select");
select.addEventListener("change", changeSelection);

function changeSelection() {
  const values = Array.from(this.querySelectorAll("option:checked")).map(opt => opt.value);
  console.log("Clicked", values);
}


var opts = select.querySelectorAll("option");
opts[0].selected = true;
opts[2].selected = true;

select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

```html
<select id="select" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you! The `dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));` was the missing part, perfect!